# API v3: Issue with GeoCoding service in Firefox 6.0 / IE 9.0

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have created a code to add multiple markers and infoWindows using the GeoCoding service. I have copied the method from API v3 Docs.  My script pulls address information from a ASP.Net web service and writes them onto a hidden div element.

```
      function codeAddress(address) 
  {
    //Get the location information from address
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    //Add a google marker onto the given address
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });

                //Prepare a infoWindow to display complete address
                var faddress = "<h4>Office Address:</h4><span>" + address + "</span>";
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: faddress});

                //Opening information window on mouseover event of marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }); 

                //closing the info window when mouse is moved out of marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(){
                    infowindow.close();
                    }); 

                } 
    });       
  }
```

Next piece of code reads the address from hidden div elements and adds the marker along with InfoWindows.  This code works perfectly with Internet Explorer 7.0/8.0.

```
  //Populate the result onto div element
  $.each(arr,function(index, item){
    $(".result").append("<div class='block'>" + item + "</div>");                
  });

  //Loop through the div element and add marker to map
  $(".block").each(function(){
        codeAddress($(this).text());
   })
```

But the same code is not working when i open it on Firefox 6.0/IE 9.0.

GeoCoding service returns ZERO_RESULTS for the same call.  When I call the method 5 times with same address it is able to add markers.

Any idea if geoCoding service has issues with new browsers ?

Thanks in Advance...

Sudhir

Comment: Further to this, I created the DIV blocks with address and adding marker on the DIV click. This works awesome in IE 8.0 but fails in Firefox 6.0. any idea what is happening,  how can Google Maps API v3 behave differently based on browser ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code im using to generate maps, you can take it and adjust it to your needs:

```
        var address = document.getElementsByTagName('address')[0].innerHTML;
        var title = document.getElementById('contact').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML;
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: title
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
```